# Не меняется пункт элемента массива объектов. Игра на JS

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

```
var canavas = document.getElementById("Ingenerka");
var vision = canavas.getContext("2d");
var personager = document.getElementById("protivnik3");
var dx = 3;
var right = false;
var left = false;
var persX = canavas.height/2+50;
var lazerY = canavas.height - 80;
var xforbullet;
var protivnik =document.getElementById("personag");
var lazerX = persX + 25;
var space = false;
var popadane = true;
var enemyes = [];
var dopschetx = 0;
var dopschety = 0;
var ddopx = 2;
var eban = [];


document.addEventListener("keyup",keyUpHandler,false);
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDownHandler,false);

function personag(){
  vision.beginPath();
  vision.clearRect(persX-5,canavas.height-50,10,50);
  vision.clearRect(persX+45,canavas.height-50,10,50);
  vision.drawImage(personager,persX,canavas.height-50,50,50);

  vision.closePath();
}
function dwigatel(){
  colisionDetect();
  drawenemy(dopschetx,dopschety,enemyes,eban);
  personag(persX);
  requestAnimationFrame(dwigatel);
  if(left && persX >= 0){
    persX-=3;
  }
  else if(right && persX+50<=canavas.height+200){
    persX +=3;
  }
  bullets.forEach(bullet => bullet.draw());
  if(space){
    if(popadane){
    new Bullet();
    popadane=false;
  }
  }

}
function drawenemy(){
for(let c=0;c<11;c++){
  for(let k=0;k<8;k++){
    if(enemyes[c][k].status===1){
      var enemyX = (c * (20 + 30)) + 30  + dopschetx;
      var enemyY = (k * (20+10)) + 30  + dopschety;
      enemyes[c][k].x=enemyX;
      enemyes[c][k].y=enemyY;
      vision.beginPath();
      vision.clearRect(enemyes[c][k].x-5,enemyes[c][k].y-6,30,30);
      vision.drawImage(protivnik,enemyes[c][k].x,enemyes[c][k].y,20,20);
      vision.closePath();
    }
  }
}
if(dopschetx>250 || dopschetx<-30){
  ddopx=-ddopx;
  dopschety+=10;
  dopschetx+=ddopx
}else dopschetx+=ddopx;
}

function colisionDetect() {
  for(let i =0;i<11;i++){
    enemyes[i]=[];
    for(let j=0;j<8;j++){
      enemyes[i][j]={x:0,y:0,status:1};
    }
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e){
  if(e.keyCode==39){
    right  = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 37){
    left = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 32){
    space  = false;
  }
}
function keyDownHandler(e){
  if(e.keyCode==39){
    right  = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 37){
    left = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 32){
    space = true;
  }
}
const bullets = [];
class Bullet {
    constructor(){
      this.x = persX+25;
      this.y = lazerY;
      bullets.push(this);
    }
    draw(){
      this.y-=5;
      if(this.y<0){
        bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(this));
        popadane = true;
        vision.clearRect(0,0,800,800);
      }
      vision.fillStyle = 'red';
      vision.clearRect(this.x,this.y,5,10);
      vision.fillRect(this.x,this.y,5,5);
      for(let c=0;c<11;c++){
        eban[c] =[];
        for(let k=0;k<8;k++){
      if(this.y<enemyes[c][k].y+30 && this.x>enemyes[c][k].x && this.x<enemyes[c][k].x+30 ){
        bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(this));
        vision.clearRect(this.x,this.y,5,10);
        popadane = true;
        enemyes[c][k]= 0;
      }
    }
      }
    }
}
dwigatel();
```

Есть массив с координатами и статусом противника. В случае совпадения координат пули и противника последний должен исчезать, но этого не происходит. Если что-то не понятно, то пишите - объясню как смогу.
P.S. Про код можно ничего не говорить, знаю что там много проблем и можно было меньше переменных юзать. Это тренировочный вариант

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Космические захватчики</title>
  <style>
  *{margin: 0;padding: 0}
    canvas{margin: 0 auto;display: block;background: black;}
  </style>
  <img src="противник.png" id="personag">
  <img src="противник3.png" id="protivnik1">
  <img src="противник2.png" id="protivnik2">
  <img src="персонаж.png" id="protivnik3">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="Ingenerka" height = "600" width = "800" style = "border:1px solid"></canvas>
<script src="Script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, Вашу разметку `html` таким образом, чтобы можно было воспроизвести Вашу проблему.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, добавил html.